# How do I understand the data-layout strings of Rust compiler targets?

Tags: rust

Inside the Rust compiler, all targets have a `data_layout`. The string looks really scary and give me nightmares. Examples for it are

```
e-m:x-p:32:32-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:32-n8:16:32-a:0:32-S32
```

and

```
e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These data layout strings are defined by **LLVM** and are [explained in the docs](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout). You could also try to learn from [the Rust compiler code that parses these strings](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.52.1/compiler/rustc_target/src/abi/mod.rs#L68).

Let's take this example:

`e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128`

- `e`: little endiann
- `m:e`: ELF mangling
- `i64:64`: native support for little endian 64 bit integers
- `f80:128`: store 80 bit floats in 128 bits
- `n8:16:32:64`: the processor has native registers for 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit
- `S128`: natural aligment of the stack in bits

What `p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64` refers to is explained here: [Many of the Rust Compilers target definitions use "p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64" inside the data-layout - what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68064553/)