# How to compile Rust code to bare metal 32 bit x86 (i686) code? What compile target should I use?

Tags: rust

I'd like to compile bare metal 32-bit code for x86 (aka i686 aka x86_64 in 32-bit mode) using cargo/Rust. What target do I need? In the [official supported target list](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/1.52.1/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec) I can't find anything, that is practical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Rust compiler doesn't have a built-in target definition [*Rust nightly 1.54, June 2021*] for this but you can provide a custom target definition:

**<project-root>/x86-unknown-bare_metal.json**

```
{
  "llvm-target": "i686-unknown-none",
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-i32:32-f80:128-n8:16:32-S128-p:32:32",
  "arch": "x86",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-pointer-width": "32",
  "target-c-int-width": "32",
  "os": "none",
  "executables": true,
  "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
  "linker": "rust-lld",
  "panic-strategy": "abort",
  "disable-redzone": true,
  "features": "+soft-float,-sse"
}
```

This definition sets the pointer width to 32 and is meant to compile code, that could be used in the early x86 boot process (when you are already in 32-bit protected mode). I'm not 100% sure about the "features", because they may depend on what you want to do/need. `i686` refers to x86_64 in 32-bit mode and the [data-layout is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67888518/how-do-i-understand-the-data-layout-strings-of-rust-compiler-targets).

In addition, you should add the file

**<project-root>/.cargo/config.toml**

```
[unstable]
# cross compile core library for custom target
build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]
build-std-features = ["compiler-builtins-mem"]

[build]
# points to file in project root
target = "x86-unknown-bare_metal.json"
```

Now you can build a bare metal binary with 32-bit x86 code using `cargo build`.

```
// disable rust standard library
#![no_std]
// disables Rust runtime init,
#![no_main]

// see https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/smallest-no-std.html
#![feature(lang_items)]

// see https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/smallest-no-std.html
#[lang = "eh_personality"]
extern "C" fn eh_personality() {}

use core::panic::PanicInfo;
use core::sync::atomic;
use core::sync::atomic::Ordering;

#[no_mangle]
/// The name **must be** `_start`, otherwise the compiler throws away all code as unused. 
/// The name can be changed by passing a different entry symbol as linker argument.
fn _start() -> ! {
    loop {}
}

#[inline(never)]
#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {
        atomic::compiler_fence(Ordering::SeqCst);
    }
}
```

For convenience, you should also add

**<project-root>/rust-toolchain.toml**

```
# With this file, another toolchain to the currently selected one will be used, when you execute `cargo build`.
# https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html

[toolchain]
# equals to rust nightly 1.54 as of the release day 2021-05-10
channel = "nightly-2021-05-10"
components = [ "rust-src", "rust-std", "rustc", "cargo" ]
```

Comment: "The name **must be** `_start`, otherwise the compiler doesn't output anything to the object file." This is because the linker removes any code it thinks unused, and `_start` is the default entry point of the program. So any function not called directly or indirectly from `_start` will be removed from the final executable. You can force a symbol to appear in the output with the `-u` linker option; or you can change the entry symbol with `-e`.