# Many of the Rust Compilers target definitions use "p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64" inside the data-layout - what does it mean?

Tags: rust, llvm

A few days ago, the basic understanding of the data layout strings of Rust compiler, or to be more specific, the underlying LLVM, was already mostly resolved on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67888518/). Unfortunately, one thing is still unclear.

Many Rust compiler targets include `p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64` inside their data layout string. Examples are `i686-unknown-uefi`, `x86_64-uwp_windows-msvc`, `x86_64-unknown-uefi`, `x86_64-unknown-linux_gnu`, `x86_64-fuchsia`, or `86_64-apple-darwin`.

(*These targets can be found here https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/1.52.1/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec.*)

The [LLVM Language Reference](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout) explains:

> **`p[n]:<size>:<abi>:<pref>:<idx>`**
> This specifies the size of a pointer and its  and erred alignments for address space n. The fourth parameter  is a size of index that used for address calculation. If not specified, the default index size is equal to the pointer size. All sizes are in bits. The address space, n, is optional, and if not specified, denotes the default address space 0. The value of n must be in the range [1,2^23).

I don't understand this. What is so special about `p270` to `p272`? To which "address space" are they referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These data layout strings were [commited to Rust on 2020-01-07](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/8b199222cc92667cd0e57595ad435cd0a7526af8). The commit message says "*Update data layouts to include new X86 address spaces*". After more research I found that the underlying functionality [was merged into LLVM in 2019](https://reviews.llvm.org/D64931). These new address spaces are MSVC's `__ptr32`, `__ptr64`, `__sptr`, and `__uptr` extensions [[1](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2019-July/134035.html)].

Quote from the LLVM discussion:

> The numbers 270-272 are more or less arbitrary; I picked them because they're near 256-258, which are the current existing address spaces.

If you look into [`X86.h` in LLVM's source code](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/release/12.x/llvm/lib/Target/X86/X86.h#L178), one can see that this number is used as identifier and is chosen at will but not for technical reasons.

Comment: In LLVM address spaces are basically arbitrary, targets give them meaning however they wants (so e.g. a bank-switched system might use a different address space for each bank to make sure not to mix them). The one exception is address space 0 (the default) and more importantly its locasiton 0, which is `nullptr`.